# Multiple languages + Htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need for a domain to manage languages (en/it/pt/es) plus remove www. and force https

```
    RewriteEngine On
    # -> www.example.com to example.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example.com
    RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
    # -> http -> https
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I don't know how to make this rewrite rule :
index.php?lg=es  -> /es/ and not /es or /es.php and even refuse index.php?lg=es

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?lg=$1
```

??

The SEO is bad for my website only english is known by engine and others languages are on the 4th page of result..

Is it the reason why because i've got two ways to display url ??

example.com/it/ and example.com/it should not return the same page

Thanks for help.

EDIT (**i think all is correct ??** ) : 07 October thanks for all answers :

```
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [OR]
      RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
      RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
      RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]{2})$ /$1/ [R=301,NC,L]
      RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]{2})/$ /index.php?lg=$1 [NC]
      RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?index.php$
      RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lg=([^&]+)(&.*)?$
      RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ - [F]
     ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Just a question : Is testing if https off really useful (slow connection ?) ? thanks

**EDIT 8 February 2018**

After months of use there are a lot of 404 errors .
**Htaccess need to more simplified**.

I just need :

```
 1) www -> non-www
 2) http -> https
 3) index.php -> example.com
 4) redirect index.php?lg=it and index.php?lg=es and index.php?lg=pt 
    to example.com/it or to example.com/es or to example.com/pt
```

and if it's not one of this language -> go to homepage example.com or 404 ?? but Google webmaster will increase 404 error ...

I need a very simplify version of htaccess with 3 languages with Rewrite Base in it ? or not ?

here is my htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]{2})$ /$1/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]{2})/$ /index.php?lg=$1 [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?index.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lg=([^&]+)(&.*)?$
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ - [F]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Everything is managed in the index.php, is it better to create 3 pages ?

index.php -> redirect to example.com

es.php -> redirect to example.com/es

it.php -> redirect to example.com/it removing .php

Can someone make it ? Thanks

Comment: We cannot tell you way your SEO is bad. There are so many possible reasons therefore this is the wrong place to discus it.

Comment: What should happen if we have a URL like example.com/it/some-page ... And example.com/it/ and example.com/it should deliver the same page IMHO, if not please explain why

Comment: Thanks for reply, i think example.com/it/ and example.com/it is maybe consider as a duplicate content ? on many website /it redirect to /it/

Comment: You used my answer only with hard code domain...

Comment: Yes i use your code but i need more points (reputation) to vote so i can't sorry..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you as accepted:

```
RewriteEngine On
# redirect to none-www and https
# if host do not starts with www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,})$ [OR]
# or if Port is 80
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
# or if https is off
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# redirect to example.com with https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect Language Strings without Trailing Slashes 
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]{2})$ /$1/ [R=301,NC,L]

# Rewrite Language string
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]{2})/$ /index.php?lg=$1 [NC]

# Prevent direct access to /index.php?lg=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?index.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lg=([^&]+)(&.*)?$
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ - [F]
```

*I tested this positive an Ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS with Apache 2.4.27*

Comment: Thanks for simplification.Only last rewrite condition does not work. Forbidden : You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server. i still need to force /lg to /lg/  is it correct ? : RewriteRule ^(en|it|pt|esp)\/?$ index.php?lg=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

Comment: and example.com/lg/text not possible just example.com/lg/

Comment: Ok, i've made multiple test and it's not working : some rules are ok www-> non www , http -> https , but example.com/es/ -> 404 error , example.com/es -> still not redirect to example.com/es/  it's not my website but i want something like dafont.com/es -> www.dafont.com/es/ (slash is added always) www.dafont.com/es.php -> 404 . I just need 2 letters index.php?lg=es not  index.php?lg=es&p=home so just $1 as a rule. Redirect index.php?lg=es -> /es/ even if more parameters are added. Thanks again

Comment: Ok, i know that cache need to be erase :) i've made a little mix and now it works : /it -> redirect to /it/ -> cool and index.php?lg=it -> You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server. The beginning of your code leads to an error for homepage so here is all the code : see on my first post on top

Comment: Ok, i try to vote for your solution but i need more points (reputation) to vote so i can't sorry...

Answer (score 2):

This solution is nice because can be applied to any domain (no hard code names).

Some notes:

1. Remove www. (no domain name hardcoded)
2. Force https (in dev environment you can work with http)
3. Add allways a slash
4. Define your default homepage if page name isn't specified
5. Mapping language and page from URL to (internal) query string

Be aware that 4 and 5 have the index.php file in public/ folder...change or remove it if you want.

---

```
# ###############################################################################
# | Rewrite engine  (SEO URLs friendly)                                            |
# ###############################################################################
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    Options +FollowSymlinks

    ## Process pages requests

  # 1. To redirect from www to non www (Rewrite www.example.com → example.com)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

  # 2. Redirect HTTP to HTTPS automatically (only if not in localhost)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # 3. (Add a slash) aa → aa/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^./]+)$ $1/

  # 4. (Default homepage) aa/ → ?lang=aa&page=home
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/$ public/index.php?lang=$1&page=home

  # 5. (Language and page) aa/bb → ?lang=aa&page=bb
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/([^./]+)$ public/index.php?lang=$1&page=$2

</IfModule>
# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

Comment: Yes you right, but if you have http:// www. example.com this will end up in 2 redirects first from non-www to www and than from http to https.

Comment: Thanks for code : but the homepage example.com does not work : connection not possible, maybe a loop ... when i change your code , i can't display homepage but /es/ is not added /es/ and /es are the same , i really need to redirect /es -> /es/ like dafont.com/es ->  dafont.com/es/ make it (it's not my website).Thanks.